# How to start node.js app on machine boot by creating a boot service

Tags: ubuntu, boot, startup, services, node.js

My machine is Ubuntu 16.04. I want to start my node.js application when the machine boots up everytime. According to this [post](https://geekflare.com/how-to-auto-start-services-on-boot-in-linux/) about autostarting services. I tried to make a service by doing the following:

1) I created a script to start node app with node's `forever` module.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting App"

forever -a start /opt/app/app.js

echo "App started"
```

2) I named this script `startApp.sh` and put this script inside **/etc/init.d/** folder.

3) I ran the command `update-rc.d startApp defaults`

But I got the error **update-rc.d: error: initscript does not exist: /etc/init.d/startApp**

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to achieve this
**PM2**
You can use PM2 which provides you to create a startup script to start up for expected or unexpected machine restarts.

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

**Docker** I prefer to create Dockerfile and run it with --restart=always tag

**If you want to continue with your shell script**
Then use unix's crontab It's very easy to use & you can configure in minutes

1. Edit crontab run the following replacing the "USER" with your desired runtime user for the node process. If you choose a different user other than yourself, you will have to run this with sudo.

   $ crontab -u USER -e
2. Once in the editor add the following line:

   @reboot /usr/local/bin/forever start /your/path/to/your/index.js
   else

   @reboot sh /your/path/to/your/startApp.sh
3. Save & confirm file is saved by check command of #1 again

   *Note: In my opinion, you should use the full path in crontab file to prevent issues*

You can refer this URL reference
[Ubuntu Cron HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)